# Bad operand types for binary operator '||' error

Tags: java

I've been trying to create a program where if the user types in `candy` or `C` into the Scanner then the program will execute some code although I'm having difficulty comparing the two variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringOrChar
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Guess a word or character");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    char c = input.charAt(0);

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("candy") || c = "C")
    {
        System.out.println("You guessed correctly.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Try again...");
    }


}
}
```

Upon running the program I receive the error " bad operand types for binary operator '||' " although I'm clueless as to how to go about fixing it. I'm aware that I could use

```
input.equals("C")
```

but I would like to know how to use the `charAt()` method.

Comment: `=` is assignment.  `==` is equality.

Comment: that aside, should you not use `c == "C"` (double equal sign)?

Comment: @Craig : I believe ajb's answer says it all, that the second condition does not make sense unless you make the input and expected output much clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes, need to correct. Though `equalsIgnoreCase` is sufficient to match `candy` or `Candy` or `CANDY`, ** anything uppercase/lowercase in word `candy`

1.) `c = "C"` **is assignment not comparison**.

2.) `c` is `char` here, so need to **compare char with char**, **not char with String**. so write  `c == 'C'`

Code should go as below.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Guess a word or character");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        char c = input.charAt(0);

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("candy") || c == 'C') {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again...");
        }
    }
```

**Ouput**

1.) User Types C

```
Guess a word or character
C
You guessed correctly.
```

2.) User Types c

```
Guess a word or character
c
Try again...
```

3.) User types candy or Candy

```
Guess a word or character
candy
You guessed correctly.
```

Comment: be the first character a `c` or 'C', i believe `equalIgnoreCase` performs the check to it already.

Comment: Also `input.charAt(0) == 'C'` could be written better as `input.startsWith("C")`. Intent is clearer.

Comment: @Andreas what is the diff between two, need to understand both options, as we have to options here, `startswith` and `chartAt`, maybe for null strings

Comment: @ankur-singhal Well, one difference is that `charAt(0)` will crash if `input` is empty, while `startsWith()` simply returns false. Both are case-sensitive, so equally bad on that point, for your use-case, as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @Andreas yes correct, i was thinking on the same terms

Comment: Actually, [ajb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37247020/5221149) has a point, so both ways are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to allow the user to type `"candy"` or `"C"`, your code won't get the job done even after you fix the compiler errors.  It's checking the first character for `C`, which means that it will match **any** user input beginning with `C`, including `Charlie`, `Caddywumpus`, etc.  If that's not what you want, then you have to compare the entire string to `"C"` and forget `charAt(0)`:

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("candy") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
```

On the other hand, if you really do want to allow any input beginning with C, you need to make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just won't require any other check

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("candy") || c == 'C' )
```

*Edit : handling only character input*

Comment: @ankur-singhal : the first condition would match it anyway as 'candy' includes a 'c'

Comment: there are three cases, `candy` and `Candy` will be handled by `equalsIgnoreCase`, but if user types just character `C`, OP wants that condition as well.